# get mysql last insert id, after inserting record using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I use PDO prepared statements to insert records. And uses [lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) to get id of inserted record. But is this good?

Because what happens when several users insert at same time? lastInsertId will conflict in that situation? So I should use transaction?

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every PHP script basically lives on its own. When several users insert at the same time, user A will get his last insert's row idA and user B will get her last insert's row idB.

Answer (score 2):

It will return the correct ID, don't worry about it.